# Create a new project with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a new symfony application by using the command : symfony new myproject.

But I get this error :

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature
>   error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation
>   failed

I'm using PHP 7.1.9 on windows 10. I verified that openSSL is enabled. I've downloaded the certicate from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem as it's mentionned in symfony docs. And i specified the certificate in my php.ini.

But the error persists.

I've tried to use composer but i got this error too while installing the composer..

Anyone could help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No i work with my personnal computer. I tried with disable my firewall but it had no effect. I should add that i tried to install composer too, into use the commands of composer instead of commands of symfony and this installation failed with a similar error.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this error?